# cannot import name 'application' in python 3

Tags: python

```
from pywinauto import application
```

**Error message:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:/Program
>   Files/Python/pywinauto.py", line 1, in 
>       from pywinauto import application   File "D:/Program Files/Python\pywinauto.py", line 1, in 
>       from pywinauto import application ImportError: cannot import name 'application'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From their documentation:**

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
```

Source: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto

Answer (score 1):

You should not name your scripts with the names of python packages.This will make your python scripts in the same location to try to import modules from these files instead of original packages.Here you should not name the script as 'pywinauto.py'.Rename it and try.Also there should not be any scripts with name 'pywinauto.py' in the same location.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is in the script name. It shouldn't be called `pywinauto.py` because Python will try to import it instead of real `pywinauto` package. Please rename your script.